# How many distinct integers can be formed by rearranging the digits of an integer. [Permutation]

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Number should not start with zero.

Example:

Given 123, ans = 3! = 6
[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]

Given 1122, ans = 4!/2! = 6
[1122, 1212, 1221, 2211, 2121, 2112]

Given 100, ans = 1
[010, 001 is NOT allowed]

I was asked to write a java code to solve this problem.
I failed to form a generic algorithm for handling zero. Please help me with a solution and some reading material.

Comment: Isn't the number of permutations of 1122 = 4! / (2! · 2!)? That's one 2! in the denominator for each group of 2 digits, whose positions interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that finds number of combinations. Suppose its called 
Integer com(List numbers); To implement this read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Now to solve the problem, First find Total numbers can be found by a com(listOfNumbers). Then find number of combinations that has 0 in the beginning and then subtract it.

For example:

1122

```
Total combinations possible com(1122) = 4! / (2! X 2!) 
Total numbers starting with 0 = 0

So ans = 4! / (2! X 2!)
```

001122

```
Total combinations possible com(001122) = 6! / (2! X 2! X 2!)
Total numbers starting with 0 
= fix one 0 in the beginning and find all possible combination for the rest of the numbers 
= com(01122) = 5! / (2! X 2!)

So ans = com(001122) - com(01122)
```

001

```
Total combinations possible com(001) = 3! / (2!) = 3
Total numbers starting with 0 
= fix one 0 in the beginning and find all possible combination for the rest of the numbers 
= com(01) = 2! = 2

So ans = com(001) - com(01) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Group your digits like this:

```
 0: m[0] times
 1: m[1] times
 2: m[2] times
 ...
 9: m[9] times
 overall number of digits: N
```

Then number of permutations is N!, and number of permutations without repeats is

```
PwR = N! / (m[0]! * m[1]!.. * m[9]!)
```

Note that there are ZwR permutations with leading zero (consider the same set without one zero (if m[0] = 0, ignore this part):

```
ZwR = (N-1)! / ((m[0] - 1)! * m[1]!.. * m[9]!)
```

So number of valid results is

```
P = PwR - ZwR = 
       N! / (m[0]! * m[1]!.. * m[9]!) - 
      (N-1)! / ((m[0] - 1)! * m[1]!.. * m[9]!) =  
  //separate common multiplier
     (N-1)! / ((m[0] - 1)! * m[1]!.. * m[9]!) * (N/m[0] - 1)
```

For your 001 example:

```
  N=3, m[0]=2, m[1] = 1
  P = (3-1)! / (1!*1!) * (3/2 - 1) = 2 * 1/2 = 1
```